# Calculate grouped means ignoring each row value

Tags: r, mean

I'm using the following code to calculate the grouped mean per class. I need the mean values of each class, placing it on each row, but ignoring each row's value for the formula (see `expected_mean` column). While that DT approach does calculate the mean, it does not ignore each row (see column `value_mean`).

```
## create dataset
dataset <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 6))
colnames(dataset) <- c('class','value')
dataset$class <- c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3))
dataset$value <- 1:6

## convert to DT and aggregate
setDT(dataset)
dataset[, value_mean := mean(value), by=class]

## expected means (without itself)
dataset$expected_means <- c(2.5,2,1.5,5.5,5,4.5)
```

And this returns:

```
   class value value_mean expected_means
       A     1          2            2.5
       A     2          2            2.0
       A     3          2            1.5
       B     4          5            5.5
       B     5          5            5.0
       B     6          5            4.5
```

I need to calculate the mean for each class, place it per row, but while ignoring the current value. For instance, for the first line, instead of `(1+2+3)/3`, it should be doing only `(2+3)/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
dataset[, expected_means := (sum(value) - value) / (.N - 1L), class]
```

Answer (score 3):

There's surely a more efficient way than `sapply`, but you could do:

```
setDT(dataset)[, value_mean := sapply(1:.N, function(x) mean(value[-x])), by = class]
```

Output:

```
   class value expected_means value_mean
1:     A     1            2.5        2.5
2:     A     2            2.0        2.0
3:     A     3            1.5        1.5
4:     B     4            5.5        5.5
5:     B     5            5.0        5.0
6:     B     6            4.5        4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)

dataset <- data.frame(class = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3), 
                      value = 1:6, 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

result = sqldf('select d.*, 
                t.sum * 1.0 / (t.count * 1.0) as value_mean, 
                (t.sum - d.value)*1.0/ ((t.count - 1) * 1.0) as expected_means
                from dataset as d JOIN 
                 (select class, sum(value) as sum, count(*) as count 
                  from dataset 
                  group by class) as t 
                on d.class = t.class')
```